# Umbraco Forms image upload to media picker

Tags: c#, umbraco7, umbraco-contour

I've read on our.umbraco.org that the Umbraco Forms' "file upload" can be used to upload images that can then be used by the media picker.

I've created a workflow which creates an Umbraco document, and I mapped the file upload to the document type's media picker and all the other properties are of course mapped as well.

Whenever I submit the form, it creates the unpublished node as it should, and it maps all the properties EXCEPT the media picker. I can't figure out why...

I'm on Umbraco version: 7.3.7.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but just for the records. For Umbraco Forms to copy a file you have to create a property on your DocType using a datatype that uses the File Upload property editor and not a media picker.

Comment: Seems this solution doesn't work correct for multiple files. Image thumbnail isn't displayed.

Comment: Because form uploader stores file pathes with separator ", " but backoffice file upload doesn't know about this(it expects only comma separated value, without space).